# Have issues with tuning hyper parameters

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm a newb, so working with the Iris dataset (with the 2 data errors fixed). Got some pretty standard stuff for a test harness:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv("iris.csv")

array = dataset.to_numpy()

X = array[:,0:4]
Y = array[:,4]

X_train, X_validation, Y_train, Y_validation = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.20, random_state=7)

knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
knn.fit(X_train, Y_train)

predictions = knn.predict(X_validation)
matrix = confusion_matrix(Y_validation, predictions)

print(f"KNN Confusion Matrix:\n\n{matrix}")
```

This results with:

```
[[ 7  0  0]
 [ 0 11  1]
 [ 0  2  9]]
```

I'm getting 3 prediction errors. Trying to improve with tuning:

```
knn = KNeighborsClassifier()

hyperparameters = {
    'n_neighbors': list(range(1, 31)),
    'leaf_size': list(range(1, 50)),
    'p': [1, 2],
    'weights':['uniform', 'distance'],
    'algorithm':['auto', 'ball_tree','kd_tree','brute']
}

kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=7, shuffle=True)

clf = GridSearchCV(knn, hyperparameters, cv=kfold, n_jobs=-1, scoring='accuracy')

best_model = clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)

print(clf.best_score_)
print(clf.best_estimator_)
print(clf.best_params_)
```

This results with:

```
0.9916666666666666
KNeighborsClassifier(leaf_size=1, n_neighbors=10, weights='distance')
{'algorithm': 'auto', 'leaf_size': 1, 'n_neighbors': 10, 'p': 2, 'weights': 'distance'}
```

But if I try (on the same X & Y above obviously):

```
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(leaf_size=1, n_neighbors=10, weights='distance')
knn.fit(X_train, Y_train)

predictions = knn.predict(X_validation)
matrix = confusion_matrix(Y_validation, predictions)

print(f"KNN Confusion Matrix:\n\n{matrix}")
```

This gives me:

```
[[ 7  0  0]
 [ 0 10  2]
 [ 0  1 10]]
```

So, no improvement whatsoever. BUT... before I found GridSearchCV, I was trying to do it manually and found:

```
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=14)
knn.fit(X_train, Y_train)

predictions = knn.predict(X_validation)
matrix = confusion_matrix(Y_validation, predictions)

print(f"KNN Confusion Matrix:\n\n{matrix}")

[[ 7  0  0]
 [ 0 11  1]
 [ 0  1 10]]
```

So that got me down to only 2 prediction errors.

I also tried LDA instead of KNN. With LDA, all default params, I only got 1 prediction error out of the box, but trying the GridSearchCV params, it shot up to 4 prediction errors.

Am I missing something? Why is GridSearchCV giving me bad params?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are slightly overstating the poor performance of the grid search. The parameters chosen by grid search are not bad at all, even if the performance does not improve by much. This is because the overall accuracy is already quite high. KNN is a simplistic model and I would not expect it to reach 100% even with parameter tuning. One thing you have to keep in mind here is that the grid search selects optimal parameters by conducting cross validation on the *training set*. There is no guarantee that the optimal parameters in the training set will carry over to the validation set. Sure, you may be able to manually find parameters that perform better on the validation set, but the point of a validation set is to set it aside until you have your final model.